# Interface Builder not showing peek and pop options for segues

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uistoryboardsegue, 3dtouch

I want to add 3D touch functionality to my app, but Interface Builder is not showing the options for peek and pop. Neither for action segues

[image: The attributes inspector showing an action segue]

nor for manual segues.
[image: The attributes inspector showing a manual segue]

My development target is iOS 9.1 and I'm using Xcode 7.2 (7C68). What gives?

Comment: Maybe you can't use 3D Touch for modal segues? Try changing the segue to a show or show detail.

Comment: That doesn't do anything, I'm afraid.

Comment: same here, could you fix it?

Answer (score 12):

peek & pop (preview commit segues options) will only appear in Interface builder if segue is initiated from UI element which is clickable or has action e.g. UIButton, UITableView Cell or UICollectionView Cell etc.

Comment: Thanks correct when I am connecting my segue by view controller it is not showing but once I connected it by cell then it is appearing.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience (I had the same problem), Peek and Pop options do not appear when I use a segue between View Controllers.

However, if I define a segue from a Table Cell or other UI items to another View Controller the pop & peek option appears. I guess this option is available when using 3D touch on specific content. If possible try defining the segue from some UI element and see if that works for you.